# Putting a label beside HTML component

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a text input. I put a label with a red star to highlight that that input is required in the form submission.
What I did is

```
<html>
<head>
</script>
<style type="text/css">

input[required] + label {
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    /*left: -230px;  the negative of the input width */
}

input[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}

/* show the placeholder when input has no content (no content = invalid) */
input[required]:invalid + label {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* hide the placeholder when input has some text typed in */
input[required]:valid + label{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="registerForm" action="submit_page.php"   method="post">
<div class="form_box">
    <div class="input_box ">
        <input maxlength="60" type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <div id="name-error" class="error-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

It works for the text input.

I did the same thing for `<select    <select/>`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<style type="text/css">
#header { background-color:green; color:white; text-align:center; padding:5px;}
#background {background: url(register_background.png);}
body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.star { color: red;} 
.button { background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 15px 32px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; margin: 4px 2px; cursor: pointer;} 
.button2:hover { box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);}
select[required] + label {
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    /*left: -230px;  the negative of the input width */
}

select[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}

/* show the placeholder when input has no content (no content = invalid) */
select[required]:invalid + label {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* hide the placeholder when input has some text typed in */
select[required]:valid + label{
    display: none;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Please add your property to advertise</h1>
</div>

<div id="background">
<form name="advertiseForm"   method="post">
<br /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="divs_states">  
     <option value="divsORstates" >Divisions or States</option>  
     <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
     <option value="fiat">Fiat</option> 
     <option value="audi">Audi</option> 
     required="required" 
<select/>  
<label for="divs_states">Please select a region</label>
<div id="divs_states-error" class="error-box"></div>

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But I don't see a red star. Then when I make a selection, the text doesn't disappear.
What should be is if the selection is `Divisions or States`, the `label Please select a region together with a red star` should appear. In case, I select saab, fiat, audi, the text should disappear.
How can I do that?
Thanks

EDIT:

```
<select name="divs_states" required="required"/>  
     <option value="divsORstates" >Divisions or States</option>  
     <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
     <option value="fiat">Fiat</option> 
     <option value="audi">Audi</option> 

<select/>  
<label for="divs_states">Please select a region</label>
<div id="divs_states-error" class="error-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that you're using the same selector from your `input` label for your `select` label.

You have this on both:

```
input[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}
```

But in your select form the HTML is different. It needs to be this instead:

```
select[name] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}
```

*A little too much cut and paste, perhaps? ;-)*

---

Also note that your closing `</select>` tag is incorrect, and you have `required="required"` misplaced in the element (ah, there it is). It should be in the opening `<select>` tag. In fact, consider running your code through the [W3C HTML Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) to check for errors.

Comment: They are two separate php files. So input and select are on separate files.  Is it the required="required" misplacement? I put it as shown in the EDIT. But it makes the label doesn't show up.

Comment: The label doesn't show up because you have it matched for `display: none` in your CSS. Remove the *////// HIGHLIGHTED CODE /////* in the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/7rfdatuL/).

Comment: thank you. How to do if want the label is shown when Divisions or States is selected and the label disappear with saab, fiat or audi are selected.

Comment: For the best answer to that question, I would recommend you post it as a new question, so it can get full attention.